# VueJs Change dragged item values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, draggable, nested-sortable

I am using [Vue Draggable](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable)

I have two lists with the "clone" option. Each list has a different Array.
I'm wondering if there is any possibility when dragging an item from list 1 to list 2, To change values to the dropped item in list 2.

For example I have in list 1 this item:

`[{"type":"text","icon":"fa fa-text"}]`

When dragged and dropped to list 2 it becomes:

`[{"type":"text","id":"XXXX", "value":"My Text is Here","style":"...."}]`

I don't know what event to list two and how to do it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [clone](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable#clone) props on the draggable component linked to list1.

Template:

```
<draggable :clone="clone" ...>
```

JS:

```
methods:{
  clone(element){
    return {
       type: element.type,
       value: "My Text is Here",
       style: "...."
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you use the  onMoveCallback function for the event handeling. The code should be something like this

```
function onMoveCallback(event, originalEvent){
    event.draggedContext.element = //whatever changes you want to make 

}
```

P.S I am not very clear on whether this is what you want . you can refer to the link in your document you mentioned

Comment: Here is the same scenario case I'm trying to make [link](https://jsfiddle.net/dede89/t3m5krea/). But when dropping a item from list to list I want to change the item value.